# Scala: how to replace strings using the original matched values

Tags: regex, scala

Is there a way to replace some string in a text using the original matched values?
For instance, I would like to replace all the integers by decimals, as in the following example:

```
"hello 45 hello 4 bye" --> "hello 45.0 hello 4.0 bye"
```

I could match all the numbers with `findAllIn` and after replace them but I would like to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using RegularExpressions, you can use `$1` to get the result of the first capturing group (in parenthesis):

```
val regex = "(\\d+)".r
val text = "hello 45 hello 4 bye"
val result = regex.replaceAllIn(text, "$1.0")
// result: String = hello 45.0 hello 4.0 bye
```

Comment: Why use `$1` when you can reference to the whole match with `$0`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yup, that's even simpler :/

Comment: And do you know how can I do some operations on `$0`? For instance: `replaceAllIn(text, "$0".take("$0".length - 1) + ".0")` does not work because of `Illegal group reference`, is it a way to do that?

Comment: You can't treat "$0" as the resulting string - it's only evaluated into the right string inside `replaceAllIn`. If you want to drop the last digit of every number before adding ".0" you''ll have to do so by capturing only the first n-1 digits and replacing the entire regex with that group: `val regex = "(\\d+)\\d".r; val result = regex.replaceAllIn(text, "$1.0")`

Answer (score 0):

Use the overload of `replaceAllIn` that takes a `replacer` function:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@replaceAllIn(target:CharSequence,replacer:scala.util.matching.Regex.Match=>String):String